# what are the compact sets in a quasi metric space which is not a metric space? example of non trivial quasi metrics?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am first time reading  quasi-metric space for my research work. I need a compact  qusi-metric( but not metric space )

Comment: $ d(x,y)=0 $ does not imply $ x=y $ is it a quasi metric. It satisfies all the condition to be a quasi-metric space except this.

Comment: (Surajit's comment was in reply to one where I confused *quasi-metric* with *pseudometric* / *semimetric*.)